# Which free tools exists to create Chiptunes / 8-bit music on Mac OSX?

Tags: mac

I've been looking for a sequencer / editor so that I can create Chiptunes on a Mac Pro workstation.

I've found some resources on [Woolyss.com](http://woolyss.com/chipmusic-mml.php) which mentions MML (Music Markup Language) is used to write that kind of music.

However, I find most of the installation processes for its suggested apps / plugins are too complicated.

Is there any standalone software (or an app that runs in the browser even) that can easily create Chiptunes on Mac OSX?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/is-there-any-windows-mac-or-unix-software-similar-to-lsdj-for-writing-chiptun

Comment: I suppose my question is very similar to your above mentioned link. I will give "Toad, Peach, and Triforce" a shot (as suggested in one of the best answers) in my DAW.

Comment: Although not free, Plogue offers a great library of Chip sounds. They seem to have a reputation for digging in junkyards to cultivate the rarest devices' sound chips and sampling / emulating them in their Chipsounds plugin. Available for Mac and Windows (AU, RTAS and VSTs) http://www.plogue.com/products/chipsounds/

Answer (score 2):

Personally I have magical 8-bit, pooBoy2, peach, rebar, toad, triforce and ymVST. All of which I got for free.

However if you are serious about making chip music I wholeheartedly recommend getting yourself an old "grey brick" Gameboy and the Little Sound DJ (LSDJ) software. As it gives you full control over the soundchip and you can achieve some great effects which are difficult to emulate with VSTs.

Hope this is helpful :D

P.S - [Here is the main site of LSDJ if you are interested](http://littlesounddj.com/lsd/)